# SELinux Error. Possibly caused from ActionBarActivity on Samsung Galaxy Mini S4

Tags: android, android-actionbar, selinux

When I create a new project choosing 'Blank Activity' in Android Studio and build it without making any edits I get an error and warnings when I test it on my Samsung Galaxy S4 mini. I do not have these issues though on the Nexus 5 emulator.

I looked around and I think it has to do with it using the "ActionBarActivity". I made sure my S4 mini is a higher version than the min SDK I chose which is API 15.

I changed my extends 'ActionBarActivity' to 'Activity', and the error goes away.

My question is I don't understand why this is happening, but more importantly is there anyway for me to use the action bar? It shows fine on the S4 Mini but I get that error.

I have the latest of Android Studio version (1.1.0). I do not have debugger running. (I saw someone mention that in a older post)

Here is the logcat, the error is the first line:

```
03-30 20:24:20.489  11164-11164/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject E/SELinux﹕ selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /seapp_contexts
03-30 20:24:20.489  11164-11164/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
03-30 20:24:20.690  11164-11164/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted
03-30 20:24:20.700  11164-11164/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 12208: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V
03-30 20:24:20.700  11164-11164/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
03-30 20:24:20.700  11164-11164/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onStopNestedScroll
03-30 20:24:20.700  11164-11164/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 12214: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll (Landroid/view/View;)V
03-30 20:24:20.700  11164-11164/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
03-30 20:24:20.700  11164-11164/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.stopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setHideOnContentScrollEnabled
03-30 20:24:20.700  11164-11164/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9779: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.stopNestedScroll ()V
03-30 20:24:20.700  11164-11164/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000e
03-30 20:24:20.700  11164-11164/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
03-30 20:24:20.710  11164-11164/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 392: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
03-30 20:24:20.710  11164-11164/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-30 20:24:20.710  11164-11164/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
03-30 20:24:20.710  11164-11164/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 414: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
03-30 20:24:20.710  11164-11164/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-30 20:24:20.710  11164-11164/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
03-30 20:24:20.710  11164-11164/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 355: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
03-30 20:24:20.710  11164-11164/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-30 20:24:20.710  11164-11164/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
03-30 20:24:20.710  11164-11164/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 357: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
03-30 20:24:20.710  11164-11164/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-30 20:24:20.820  11164-11164/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
03-30 20:24:20.830  11164-11164/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
03-30 20:24:20.830  11164-11164/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
03-30 20:24:20.840  11164-11164/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject I/Adreno200-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:265>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AYELDER_AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_2.5.5.04.02.02.092.023+PATCH[ES]_msm8960_JB_2.5.5_CL3556704_release_ENGG (CL3556704)
    Build Date: 05/17/13 Fri
    Local Branch:
    Remote Branch: quic/jb_2.5.5
    Local Patches: 34c9e193f12610d3e68dabd6198d2c4bfbc66974 RB: Update the master timestamp of the hw_image in rb_texture_update_aliased
    Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_2.5.5.04.02.02.092.023 + 01d3c78 + e6f0547 +  LOCAL_PATCH[ES]
03-30 20:24:20.900  11164-11164/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
03-30 20:25:36.180  11164-11170/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject D/dalvikvm﹕ Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
03-30 20:26:04.190  11954-11954/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted
03-30 20:26:04.190  11954-11954/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 12208: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V
03-30 20:26:04.190  11954-11954/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
03-30 20:26:04.190  11954-11954/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onStopNestedScroll
03-30 20:26:04.190  11954-11954/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 12214: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll (Landroid/view/View;)V
03-30 20:26:04.190  11954-11954/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
03-30 20:26:04.190  11954-11954/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.stopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setHideOnContentScrollEnabled
03-30 20:26:04.190  11954-11954/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9779: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.stopNestedScroll ()V
03-30 20:26:04.190  11954-11954/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000e
03-30 20:26:04.200  11954-11954/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
03-30 20:26:04.200  11954-11954/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 392: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
03-30 20:26:04.200  11954-11954/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-30 20:26:04.200  11954-11954/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
03-30 20:26:04.200  11954-11954/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 414: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
03-30 20:26:04.200  11954-11954/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-30 20:26:04.200  11954-11954/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
03-30 20:26:04.200  11954-11954/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 355: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
03-30 20:26:04.200  11954-11954/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-30 20:26:04.200  11954-11954/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
03-30 20:26:04.200  11954-11954/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 357: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
03-30 20:26:04.200  11954-11954/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-30 20:26:04.270  11954-11954/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
03-30 20:26:04.320  11954-11954/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
03-30 20:26:04.320  11954-11954/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
03-30 20:26:04.320  11954-11954/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject I/Adreno200-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:265>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AYELDER_AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_2.5.5.04.02.02.092.023+PATCH[ES]_msm8960_JB_2.5.5_CL3556704_release_ENGG (CL3556704)
    Build Date: 05/17/13 Fri
    Local Branch:
    Remote Branch: quic/jb_2.5.5
    Local Patches: 34c9e193f12610d3e68dabd6198d2c4bfbc66974 RB: Update the master timestamp of the hw_image in rb_texture_update_aliased
    Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_2.5.5.04.02.02.092.023 + 01d3c78 + e6f0547 +  LOCAL_PATCH[ES]
03-30 20:26:04.360  11954-11954/erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
```

Here is the MainActivity.xml code:

```
package erasenothigntest.com.erase_testproject;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And here is the layout xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"  tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world"  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks